# Numpy precision with exponentials of imaginary numbers

Tags: python, numpy

The function exp(ix) is periodic in x, with period 2*pi. The `np.exp()` function is able to handle complex arguments; however, it starts incurring errors as the size of the argument increases; i.e, the expression

```
np.exp(1) - np.exp(1+2*np.pi*x*1j)
```

is not zero for integer `x`, and the deviation from zero increases as `x` increases. What is the best way to minimize the errors that these sorts of expressions incur for large `x`?

Comment: what is exactly the problem? give an example for a large `x`.

Comment: Ignoring the exp part, from a simple floating point perspective, the floats get denser as you get closer to zero, so the bigger the number is the larger the absolute error. So the bigger x is, the more incorrect `1+2*np.pi*x*1j` is.

Comment: I don't think there is a good general solution. But as long as you have the x neatly isolated as multiplier to 2pi i you can do `np.exp(1) - np.exp(1+2*np.pi*(x%1)*1j)`. This will not remedy the reduced resolution of large floating point numbers but it will avoid amplifying the error due to pi not being exact.